# Bootstrap nav dropdown under wrong item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Alrighty, as asked, here is my question reformatted:

I am using bootstrap. My nav bar has a drop-down. But the drop-down is appearing under the wrong nav item.

This is only happening for me on FireFox 20.0 on a 2010 MacPro OSX 10.8.3

It does work on other browsers (Chrome and Safari)

Here are some links. The nav item at the far right (Zone Tools) should have the dropdown.

Image alone: 
tinypic.com/r/e0kqp/5

Code is put up here. Little funkyness because I tried to strip it down to just the nav bar, but you'll get the gist.

http://bootply.com/61045

I have more links, but I cannot put more than two in at a time so far.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem. Which browser? Are you resizing the browser? I looked at 'ztest.html' and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Hey Skelly, thanks for checking it out. I actually didn't try it on multiple browsers because the first one I used it didn't work, so I didn't bother to check if it was working on other browsers. And waddaya know, works on my ipad in landscape. Anyhoo - Mac Firefox latest version is where it's not working for me. Window size full, so it's not that the window is too small. Don't think too big should matter on the one. Thank you again!

Comment: If you want help on SO you should update your question to be more specific. Include details on how it doesn't work in FF and what you've tried. jsFiddle or http://bootply.com (Bootstrap playground) are helpful to demonstrate what you've tried and what's not working in a specific way!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is this in your CSS..

```
  .navbar .nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    float: none;
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .navbar .nav ul li {
    display: table-row;
    width: 1%;
    float: none;
    font-size: 13px;
  }
```

When you remove this it works, but you'll need to figure out another way to center your nav items. http://bootply.com/61059

P.S. - you don't need to include the Bootstrap scripts in Bootply.